# There is some problem with my code. I want to convert the conventional if into elvis operator. what should I do then?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is my code
what should I do to this function, I need to convert into elvis operator

```
fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?): String {
    val result = if (valueC != null) {
        valueA + (valueB - valueC)
    } else {
        100
    }
    return generateResult(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can write like this but from my point of view your initial version is more readable

```
fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?): String {
    val result = valueC?.let { valueA + (valueB - it) } ?: 100
    return generateResult(result)
}
```

Comment: thanks but I have one last problem 

`fun generateResult(result: Int) = ""`

what should I do to the function if I want to get "text" as return value, Should I add `.toString` like this ?

`fun generateResult(result: Int) = "".toString()`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your problem. `fun generateResult(result: Int) = ""` and `fun generateResult(result: Int) = "".toString()` will return exactly the same string value - `""`

Comment: ya I think so, but I still get an error with that code

Comment: take a look here I didn't get my result with this [link](https://pl.kotl.in/Mcls4l1Oj)

Comment: the result must like this `Result is 39`

Comment: how if I won't make the code to handle if the valueC == null then give the default value 100

Comment: sorry, I don't get your question

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I would just use an one-line `if-else` expression without curly brackets:

```
fun calculate(valueA: Int, valueB: Int, valueC: Int?): String {
    val result = if(valueC != null) valueA + valueB - valueC else 100
    return generateResult(result)
}
```